# Cálculos dobras cutâneas

Tags: java, matemática

Bom, eu não sei se posso pedir ajuda em relação a calculo, mais de toda forma, minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Eu preciso fazer o calculo de dobras cutâneas, neste caso o calculo de Pollok 3 dobras, pesquisei na internet, mais não é algo tão fácil de compreender, gostaria de saber, se a maneira com a qual eu estou fazendo esta correta. Eu ia postar apenas o calculo, mais fiz também um exemplo executável (exemplo bem simples) para poder ilustrar a situação melhor.

Eu usei estas informações como base:

```
Para 3 dobras:
DC= 1,10938 – 0,0008267 (X2) + 0,0000016 (X2)
2 – 0, 0002574 (X3)
Legenda:
DC= Densidade Corporal em g/ml    
X2 = soma das 3 dobras (tórax, abdominal e coxa)
X3 = idade em anos
```

Obs: página 36 : https://sandrodesouza.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/perimetria-dobras-cutaneas-e-protocolos.pdf

Código:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class DobrasCuteneas extends JFrame {

    JTextField campoPeitoral = new JTextField();
    JTextField campoAbdominal = new JTextField();
    JTextField campoCoxa = new JTextField();
    JTextField campoGorduraIdeal = new JTextField();
    JButton botao = new JButton("Calcular");

    public DobrasCuteneas() {
        setTitle("Exemplo");
        add(tela());
        pack();
        acaoBotao();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    private void acaoBotao() {
        botao.addActionListener((ActionEvent ae)
                -> {
            calculo();
        });
    }

    private JPanel tela() {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label01 = new JLabel("Peitoral:");
        painel.add(label01);
        painel.add(campoPeitoral);
        campoPeitoral.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        JLabel label02 = new JLabel("Abdominal:");
        painel.add(label02);
        painel.add(campoAbdominal);
        campoAbdominal.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        JLabel label03 = new JLabel("Coxa:");
        painel.add(label03);
        painel.add(campoCoxa);
        campoCoxa.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        painel.add(botao);
        botao.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 20));
        JLabel label04 = new JLabel("Gordura ideal:");
        painel.add(label04);
        painel.add(campoGorduraIdeal);
        campoGorduraIdeal.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        add(painel);

        return painel;
    }

    private void calculo() {
        float peitoral = Float.valueOf(campoPeitoral.getText().replaceAll(",", "."));
        float abdominal = Float.valueOf(campoAbdominal.getText().replaceAll(",", "."));
        float coxa = Float.valueOf(campoCoxa.getText().replaceAll(",", "."));
        float idade = 25;
        Float x2 = (peitoral + abdominal + coxa);

        Float densidadeCorporal = (float) (1.10938 - x2) + (x2 * 2) - idade;
        System.out.println("Densidade corporal: " + densidadeCorporal);
        Float percentualGordura = ((float) ((4.95 / densidadeCorporal) - 4.50) * 100);
        System.out.println("Percentual de gordura: " + percentualGordura);
        campoGorduraIdeal.setText("" + percentualGordura);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(()
                -> {
            DobrasCuteneas dobras = new DobrasCuteneas();
            dobras.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

E para o calculo final (gordura ideal) :

```
%G = [(4,95/Densidade Corporal) - 4,50] x 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na formula para a densidade corporal ficaram a faltar os coeficientes assim como o quadrado de `X2`. Relembrando que a mesma é (pelo pdf indicado):

> DC= 1,10938 – 0,0008267 (X2) + 0,0000016 (X2)^2 – 0,0002574 (X3)

E que foi aplicada como:

```
Float densidadeCorporal = (float) (1.10938 - x2) + (x2 * 2) - idade;
```

Os coeficientes de `0,0008267`, `0,0000016` e `0,0002574` não foram utilizados.

Para corrigir basta trocar a formula para:

```
Float densidadeCorporal = 1.10938 - (0.0008267 * x2) + (0.0000016 * x2 * x2) - (0.0002574 * idade);
```

Comment: Nesse caso, ele acaba me retornando valores como -421.000 por exemplo, eu acredito que isso não esteja correto.

Comment: @GustavoSantos De facto também faltava o coeficiente para a `idade`. Confirme agora se obtêm os valores esperados